# Query to get all the columns in a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got this little ditty to concatenate all the columns in a table, for writing scripts quickly:

```
    create function [dbo].[get_columns] (@table_name varchar(255))
    returns varchar(max)

    as
    begin
    declare @name varchar(255),
    @object_id varchar(255),
    @string varchar(max)


    set @object_id = (select object_id from sys.objects with (nolock) where name = @table_name and type = 'u')

    set @string = (select stuff( (
    select ', ' + name   from sys.columns with (nolock)
    where object_id = @object_id
    and name != 'row_timestamp'
    for xml path ('')),1,2,''))

    return @string
    end
```

**Question:** how would you re-write this to get the columns of a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have one function for tables and a separate function for views? You can handle both just by removing the restrictive filter on `type = 'u'` (and actually you don't need `sys.objects` at all). Here is a rewrite with some other minor enhancements:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_columns
(
  @object_name nvarchar(513) 
  -- needs to support Unicode!
  -- should pass schema.object
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) -- can contain Unicode!
AS
BEGIN -- we don't need any variables
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT N', ' + name 
      FROM sys.columns WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@object_name)
      AND name <> N'row_timestamp'
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
  );
END
```

Comment: oh! I forgot I put that in! I've been using this same function for years. When you get to be my age...

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap this in a  inline table valued functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_all_columns
    ( @tablename sysname,@schemaname sysname ) 
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN 
SELECT TABLE_NAME,STUFF((SELECT N', ' + p2.COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS p2
   WHERE p2.TABLE_NAME = p.TABLE_NAME 
   ORDER BY p2.ORDINAL_POSITION
   FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'') AS columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS p
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename AND TABLE_SCHEMA=@schemaname
GROUP BY p.TABLE_NAME
GO
```

then join with table information schema

```
SELECT            a.*,
                  d.*
FROM              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES                         a
      CROSS APPLY dbo.get_all_columns(a.TABLE_NAME, a.TABLE_SCHEMA) d;
```

for getting the columns in a view as you said change the query the information schema `VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_all_columns_view
    ( @viewname sysname,@schemaname sysname ) 
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN 
SELECT VIEW_NAME,STUFF((SELECT N', ' + p2.COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE p2
   WHERE p2.VIEW_NAME = p.VIEW_NAME
   ORDER BY p2.VIEW_NAME
   FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'') AS columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE p
WHERE p.VIEW_NAME = @viewname AND p.VIEW_SCHEMA=@schemaname
GROUP BY p.VIEW_NAME
GO
```

Comment: The question was about getting this for views, your answer will only work for tables.

Comment: And `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is only worthwhile when your goal is to make very generic schema queries that work across different RDBMS platforms.

Comment: @JonathanFite, just added another function for that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Yup,the easiest way to fetch the column names of table by passing the table name is information_schema, just took a shortcut :)

Comment: Why is that easier than sys.columns?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, two joins sys.columns and sys.objects , if its info_schema just query the information_schema.columns and pass the tablename as parameter

Comment: @AaronBertrand, but this requires two functions but as you per above answer both can be handled in same code.

Comment: Your solution connects to these INFORMATION_SCHEMA views twice and "joins" them. Besides look at the definition for those INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, they just abstract these joins from you (and perform an extra join each, to boot). The function I wrote still makes the interface simple - you can pass `tablename` or `dbo.tablename` and everything else is simplified away. I also stay away from INFORMATION_SCHEMA [for reasons I describe here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, oops, so caution to be taken when using INFO_SCHEMA

Comment: Yes, information_schema is basic by design, leaves out all kinds of proprietary information (where are indexes for example?), and is really just a wrapper around the correct joins against richer views. Also, the join I originally wrote in my answer was unnecessary.